# Disable globally ripple effect angular 2 app

Tags: angular, material-design

I have an app which is using material 2, i would like to globally disable the ripple effect for all components or directives that use it. I don't want to do this overriding css classes. One thing that comes in my mind is creating a directive which can extend MdRipple and then override its properties, not sure tho. I would like to know your opinion or example how this can be done in the right way.

Answer (score 9):

The provider changed in recent versions. You need to use MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS not MD_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS.

Update your AppModule.ts

```
...

import {  MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, RippleGlobalOptions } from '@angular/material';

const globalRippleConfig: RippleGlobalOptions = {
  disabled: true
};

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    ...
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [{provide: MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue:     globalRippleConfig}]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Kurt can you please also guide how to set duration of the animation. I tried the approach mentioned https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/overview#updating-global-options-at-runtime but it does't seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

Import ripple specific token and interface

```
import { MD_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, RippleGlobalOptions } from '@angular/material';
```

then create config

```
const globalRippleConfig: RippleGlobalOptions = {disabled: true};
```

then add new provider to your main NgModule

```
providers: [{provide: MD_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: globalRippleConfig}]
```

With MD_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS you can also configure ripple size, color, animation speed

Comment: For the latest versions of Angular Material it's `MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS` you need to import, otherwise this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

As a slightly simpler alternative, if you only want to disable the ripple effect completely, you don't need a `const globalRippleConfig`, you can just put it inline.

So the `import` looks like this:

```
// maybe '@angular/material' below depending on your material version
import {MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material/core';
```

and in `NgModule`:

```
providers: [
    { provide: MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {disabled:true} },
    // and any other providers here
],
```